# TS 7006 error when following documentation for upgrading Firebase Functions from Gen 1 to Gen 2

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade) for migrating to Gen 2 Firebase Functions say restructure my triggers to look like the code below:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

exports.date = onRequest({cors: true}, (req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

However, when I use this same example in my script, it gives two errors:

> Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

> Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

The docs don't show a way to handle this, so what is the recommended thing to do here? From my own research, I see that I could change `(req, res)` to `(req: any, res: any)`, but I don't have enough experience with Typescript to know if this is a good solution.